# relay for USB camera control

Tags: usb, pwm

I need a little help with some electronic components:

From my RC system a I get a signal which is 3.3V PWM, 5 volt and GND.

I need to make a 5V PWM out of this for my camera. 
PWM values are 1-32ms and need to be identical (3.3V input PWM= 5V output PWM)

I was thinking of a relay or transistor but I'm not sure about that.

Can somebody help me with a schematic and shopping list?

Comment: Meanwhile I solved it with a simple logic buffer. A 2N2222 and 2pcs of 220ohm resistor. BUT I have to take this one step further: I need 2 signal sources(2RC channels 3.3V pwm) merged into 1 (5V pwm).

Answer (score 1):

The below circuit i have drawn can be  a simple solution to start with.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9RuvV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a transistor or a IC buffer (op-amp or logic buffer).

A relay is too slow for servo PWM signals.

These [google pictures](https://www.google.com/search?q=level%20shifter3.3V%205V&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=4FycVZu-JefgywOEg7vICg&ved=0CCwQsAQ&biw=1400&bih=778) should give you more choice than you can use.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is getting a `74LVC1T45` which is a tiny chip for your purpose.

Since it is small enough with a 0603-size bypass cap you can build it right next to either side of the wire, or if you are using it to the flat flex you are using to connect the two portions of the board.